# Yii2 Model ViaTable

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

For simplicity, lets say I have 3 tables: `menu`, `page` and a junction table `menu_page`.

So If I want to get all menus which are available for page "home", in the model I defined a relationship:

```
public function getAllMenus() {
    return $this->hasMany(Menu::className(), ['id' => 'menu_id'])->viaTable(PageMenu::tableName(), ['page_id' => 'id']);
}
```

But now we have added an attribute to menu table called `show_all_pages`, if this is set as 1, menu should be returned, if not we should check if menu is enabled to be used on home.

Is there a way to add this condition here?

Comment: do you want it to be globally integrated within the relation or it is required for any specific `controller` or `action` ?

Comment: In the relation

Comment: the below answer should work then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found so far was doing to separate Active Queries and do a Union:

```
public function getSelectedMenus() {

        return $this->hasMany(Menu::className(), ['id' => 'menu_id'])->viaTable(PageMenu::tableName(), ['page_id' => 'id'])->onCondition(['menu.active' => Page::ACTIVE]);
    }

    public function getAllMenus() {
        return Menu::find()->where(['active' => Page::ACTIVE, 'show_all_pages' => 1]);
    }

    public function getMenus() {

        $selectedMenus = $this->getSelectedMenus();
        $allMenus = $this->getAllMenus();

        return $selectedMenus->union($allMenus);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of an [`andWhere`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#andWhere()-detail) clause to apply this filter on `show_all_pages`

```
public function getAllMenus() {
    return $this->hasMany(Menu::className(), ['id' => 'menu_id'])
                ->viaTable(PageMenu::tableName(), ['page_id' => 'id'])
                ->andWhere(['show_all_pages' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are adding an extra condition over the query which is already doing a join with pagemenu. The idea is that a menu can have field show_all_pages but no records on pagemenu table.

Comment: @Eduardo "you are adding an extra condition over the query which is already doing a join with pagemenu" - this is correct, however the next part of your comment I do not understand, but effectively this `andWhere` serves to add in `show_all_pages = 1` to the `WHERE` clause of the generated sql

Comment: My case I need or doing the join using viaTable or using show_all_pages attribute condition, both can not be applied.